# Where can I find a list of all Media options in libVLC

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I used the command prompt command

`vlc --longhelp`

Which generates a long text file, but it's missing a bunch of options like

`network-caching`, or any caching.

Anyone have any insight into a complete list of options for the Media object in libvlc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vlc -H`

```
vlc -H | grep caching
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
      --sout-livehttp-caching, --no-sout-livehttp-caching 
      --sout-udp-caching <integer> 
          Default caching value for outbound UDP streams. This value should be
          high values, you will need to raise caching values.
      --sout-rtp-caching <integer> 
          Default caching value for outbound RTP streams. This value should be
          caching at input.
      --file-caching <integer [0 .. 60000]> 
                                 File caching (ms)
      --live-caching <integer [0 .. 60000]> 
                                 Live capture caching (ms)
      --disc-caching <integer [0 .. 60000]> 
                                 Disc caching (ms)
      --network-caching <integer [0 .. 60000]> 
                                 Network caching (ms)
      --sout-mux-caching <integer> 
                                 Stream output muxer caching (ms)
          This allow you to configure the initial caching amount for stream
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure this wiki page is versioned to the libvlc version, but here you go https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/